# How can I trigger opening a select form's options on click of another button in react? I have tried using a ref but its not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref, react-forms

Here is my select form:

```
<form ref={skuSelectRef}>
    <label htmlFor="size" />
    <select
        id="size"
        value={selectedSKU}
        onChange={() => changeSKU(size.options[size.selectedIndex].value)}
    >
        <option value="default">
            {outOfStock ? 'OUT OF STOCK' : 'SELECT SIZE'}
        </option>
        {availableSizes.map((size, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={size}>
                {size}
            </option>
        ))}
    </select>
</form>
```

The button that when I click I would like for the select form above to open:

```html
<div className="a2cbtn">
    <button onClick={onAddToCartClick} id="a2cbtn">
        <span>ADD TO CART</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Both of the above components are in my AddToCart subcomponent. Here is a snippet of the button click handler in the parent component where I am trying to make the select form open:

```js
if (this.state.selectedSKU === 'default') {
    this.skuSelectRef.current.click();
    console.log(this.skuSelectRef);
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

It seems that the ref is properly created because I am getting `{current: form}` logged to the console and the click is working as I'm getting "clicked" logged to the console as well. However the select form is not opening!

At first I tried having the ref in my select element instead of form but then when I clicked the button it gave me an error saying that the function click doesn't exist so I moved the ref to the form element enclosing it and now I am not getting that error but it is still not opening.

I have tried `this.skuSelectRef.current.focus()` and `this.skuSelectRef.current.select()` as well to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would create a useState like 'formEnabled', control its state onclick Button and with this variable i could show/or not the form based on click. You need to set this using Ref?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto The question is how to actually show the form..?

Comment: Yes, i would do that with a useState variable to control the form visibility.

Comment: Your form and 'Add Cart' button are in the same component, right?  If you click the button you toggle the visibility of the form, its that what you want?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto Yes....the question is how do you actually trigger the select form opening programatically? Obviously you can open it if you click on it in the browser but how I can open it on a click of another button? I can use state all I want to control whether it should be variable or not but that doesn't answer my question of HOW to open the form

Comment: Maybe this could help you: [how-to-show-a-form-in-the-same-window-on-onclick-event-of-a-button-in-react-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605846/how-to-show-a-form-in-the-same-window-on-onclick-event-of-a-button-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **focus** the select when clicking the button, that can be done with refs.  It's not working for you because you attached the ref to the `form` element and you need to be attaching it to the `select` element directly.

```
const skuSelectRef = createRef();

const onAddToCartClick = () => {
    if (size === "default") {
        skuSelectRef.current?.focus();
    }
};
```

```
<select ref={skuSelectRef} ....
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-63382309-42g8f?file=/src/App.tsx)

If you want to **open** the select element, that's tough.  There is no `open()` method like there is for `focus()`.  There's a whole discussion about how to do it [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due).  But I would recommend that you not reinvent the wheel.  There are lots of libraries for form and UI components that can do this via a `boolean` `open` prop. Material UI is one of the biggest.  [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtmod) is their demo for a controlled open.